# Inno Setup: Cancel uninstalling

Tags: inno-setup

By default cancel button is disabled during uninstall process. I've set it to true, but system close control is still inactive, and clicking Cancel button doesn't affect on uninstallation. What is the best way to safety roll-back uninstallation process?

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot rollback uninstallation in Inno Setup. No way.